# Как сделать автопозиционирование баллуна метки без передвижения карты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Не могу разобраться как сделать так, чтобы если метка расположена близко к краю карты, то баллун сдвигается вправо, влево, вверх, вниз в зависимости от края карты и без движения самой карты.
Подскажите пожалуйста.
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Баллун не стоит на месте ,у вас смещена картинка балуна, кончик балуна должен указывать на место, а у вас сейчас указывает не кончик баллуна, а левая верхняя часть балуна, это легко поправить, на ютубе есть видео посмотрите.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkfUqb2XFRw&t=708s здесь ответ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkfUqb2XFRw&list=PLRdm4iTnaFk1GEGBmnCL8jvHBCSL-0D3R&index=2 или здесь

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.